# Not able to push maven dependency through git push

Tags: maven, openshift

Do I need to do any configuration change while pushing the code to openshift. Earlier I was able to push without any problem. After re-installing RUBY and GIT it has started giving problem. Below is the error which I am getting:

> remote: [ERROR] Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.10 in eap
>   (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all) -> [Help 1]

Please help me, I am stuck and not able to understand what needs to be done.

Comment: What version of Ruby did you install?

Comment: I have installed Ruby22-x64

Comment: I added my comment without your error being stated. However, I use Ruby 2.0.  I know there are problems with later versions of ruby